# bash command to either open one command or another command

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, makefile

I am using two different OSes.

- for MacOS : open file.pdf  ( it opens pdf in default pdf program in Mac)
- for Linux : xdg-open file.pdf ( it does so in Linux)

If I interchange the command it doesnot work.
Is there any single line set of commands like:

- open file.pdf or xdg-open file.pdf

I want a command (or commands) that works for both of them without showing any error.
The place where I need this command is in make file.

I have a makefile like this:

```
all:
open file.pdf
xdg-open file.pdf
other things ..
```

Here, inside the makefile how can I be sure that make commands run without
error both in Mac and in Linux?

Thanks to @rubiks, now the code works fine.
The code looks like this:

```
# set pdfviewer for linux and unix machines
####################################################

UNAME_S := $(shell uname -s)

$(info $$UNAME_S == $(UNAME_S))

ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Linux)
PDFVIEWER := xdg-open
else ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Darwin)
PDFVIEWER := open
else

$(error unsupported system: $(UNAME_S))
  endif
$(info $$PDFVIEWER == $(PDFVIEWER))
####################################################
# open the pdf file
default: all
    $(PDFVIEWER) my_pdf_filename.pdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind invoking the shell, you can query the system from within the `Makefile` and set `PDFVIEWER` accordingly:

```
UNAME_S := $(shell uname -s)

$(info $$UNAME_S == $(UNAME_S))

ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Linux)
  PDFVIEWER := xdg-open
else ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Darwin)
  PDFVIEWER := open
else
  $(error unsupported system: $(UNAME_S))
endif

$(info $$PDFVIEWER == $(PDFVIEWER))
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks to @rubiks. If i had more than 15 points I would have given upvote for you.

Comment: @BhishanPoudel  it's all good---I'm just happy you got something working for you! :-)

Answer (score 7):

I think it is better to do this a little more intelligently and determine the OS you are on:

```
if [ `uname` == "Darwin" ]; then
  open file.pdf
else
  xdg-open file.pdf 
fi
```

If you are trying to configure your terminal so that you can always use the same command, I would recommend adding this to your .bashrc or .bash_profile:

```
if [ `uname` == "Linux" ]; then
   alias open=xdg-open
fi
```

This way, you can always use the command `open` and it will work on either OS.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use `which` to return first available executable, e.g.

```
open  := $(shell which open xdg-open | head -n1)
xargs := $(shell which gxargs xargs  | head -n1) # Another example.
```

then run it as:

```
$open file.pdf
```